# flutter how to use alertDialog?

Tags: flutter

I'm making sign in system in flutter.

I want to use alertDialog for sign in failed.

if-else is included in onpressed:

```
else {
                      AlertDialog(
                        title: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Text("Log in failed"),
                          ],
                        ),
                        //
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "ID or Password doesn't exist",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          new FlatButton(
                            child: new Text("OK"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
```

Writing return doesn't work and  deleting  return doesn't show anything.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `showDialog` and pass the `AlertDialog` you created.

The demo I created on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/aa616edbc966247f8a569df39f52f183).

```dart
await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Log in failed"),
      ],
    ),
    //
    content: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "ID or Password doesn't exist",
        ),
      ],
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
        child: new Text("OK"),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Note: Use TextButton instead of FlatButton because FlatButton is [deprecated](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons).

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this helped, you can mark it as accepted.